# Scala add value to a char variable

Tags: scala

I am creating a simple function in Scala

```
def addOne(m: Int): Int = m + 1
```

Using it with integers works normally, using double it throws a type mismatch error.

```
addOne(2) = 3
addOne(2.1) = error: type mismatch
```

When I use it with a character in double quotes, it throws a type mismatch as expected.

```
addOne("z") = error: type mismatch
```

However, when using a single quotes character it returns a value for that letter.

```
addOne('z') = 123
```

What is happening here and why is it like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you can use a `Char` as an argument to a function taking an `Int` is because Scala performs an implicit conversion from `Char` to `Int`. This specific conversion is defined in the companion object of the `Char` class. See here:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/Char$.html (It seems like SO breaks this link at the $ character. Copy-paste it instead)

The function perfoming the conversion is called `char2int`. It converts the `Char` into its corresponding Unicode value as an `Int`.

When the Scala compiler sees that the types `Char` and `Int` don't match, it will first check if there are any available implicit conversions. It only gives a compile error if it didn't find any. If it finds an implicit conversion, it will insert that function call into your code. Your code is therefore transformed to this:

```
addOne(Char.char2int('z'))
```

If you want to make your own implicit conversion to, for example, let your function accept `String`, you can define this:

```
// Enable implicit conversions.
import scala.language.implicitConversions

// The "implicit" modifier is the important part here, not the name of the function.
implicit def string2int(s: String) = s.toInt
```

Now this compiles:

```
// This returns 6
addOne("5")

/* 
 * This throws a NumberFormatException due to my implementation of string2int.
 * Create your own implementation of string2int if you want it to work properly.
 */
addOne("a")
```

Finally: Beware that implicit conversions are very powerful and therefore can be dangerous! See TheArchetypalPaul's comment for an explanation.

Comment: ...and we have the only full and correct answer. For extra credit :D you could show how one could add an implicit from String to Int and so make it work for that? Upvoted anyway

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Good suggestion, fixed.

Comment: Implicits are very powerful and it's easy to blow your own foot off with them. So while this is a great explanation of how it works, doing implicit conversions on widely used types like `String` is normally not a good idea as the implicit can kick in when you didn't want it. For instance, with @marstran's `String` implicit, you could type the wrong quotes, call `addOne("9")` and get a different result from what you were expecting from `addOne('9'')` - and nothing from the compiler to warn you. Personally, I'm not convinced even the standard `Char` -> `Int` one is a good idea...

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I completely agree. There is a reason they must be enabled with the import.

Answer (score -1):

It is because `addOne(m: Int)` [The part after colon (:) ] tells Scala you will pass Int to it, not Double, not anything else.

if you want it to work for Double, try this, but then you will always get Double as Result.

```
def addone (m : Double ) =  m+1
addone: (m: Double)Double

scala> addone(1)
res0: Double = 2.0

scala> addone(1.1)
res1: Double = 2.1
```

Comment: what is happening with the single quotes then?

Comment: single quotes are converted to their ASCII representation. 'a' being 97 and 'b' being 98 and so on.. If you use double quotes, it is a String and not converted to ASCII representation. Google ASCII if you want more information.

Comment: But you haven't answered why that conversion to ASCII happens. So I think this answer is rather incomplete

Comment: Actually, this is even more wrong. It is NOT that single-quoted values are converted to ASCII. It's that Char values are implicitly converted to Int *if and only if* an `Int` value is expected as the argument. And ANY `Char` value will be converted, not just literals contained in single quotes. If you defined `addToChar(c:Char)` then `addChar('z')` would receive a Char value and not the corresponding `Int` of 122.

Answer (score -1):

Scala map the char type using the [ASCII Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). So, `'z'` is mapped to 122, which is an integer. In the method, `addOne('z')`, the input parameter been cast to an integer (i.e. 122).

However, the input parameter in `addOne(2.1)` is 2.1, which is a double and in  `addOne("z")` is a string. They cannot be cast to an integer automatically.

Comment: This doesn't really explain why the Scala compiler accepts a `Char` value into a function taking an `Int`. There's not an automatic "mapping" to ASCII values that is happening. It is an implicit conversion. See my answer.

Comment: @marstran what I meant was 'z' is mapped to 122 according to the ASCII table not the `map` function or anything to do with Scala. You are right, Scala converts a char type to an integer implicitly.

Answer (score -1):

`def addOne(m: Int): Int = m + 1` only accept an integer for `m`
It also work with a single quoted character (`z`) because it's translated into its ASCII value. The value for 'z' is 122 and you add 1.

scala> val foo: Int = 'z'
 foo: Int = 122

scala> val bar = foo + 1
bar: Int = 123

If you want to make this working with double you can specify `def addOne(m: Double): Double = m + 1`

Comment: returning integer after adding 1 to Double is not good practice. It will result in loss of precision.

Comment: You're right. Simple copy/paste error ! I fixed it, thanks.

Comment: "because it's translated into its ASCII value" Well, yes but that's just stating it works because it works. The interesting answer would be _why_ it is translated into its ASCII value.